# Explanation for Ruby Solution to "Smallest Positive Number Divisible By"

Tags: ruby

I'm seeking a line by line explanation of how this solution works. It finds the smallest positive number that can be divided all the numbers from 1 through 20 without any remainder.

```
test = 20
divisor = 0

while true

  # Don't check factors from 1-10, since all included in 11-20. Plus check backwards from 20 down, to save time.
  20.downto(11) do |d|  
    divisor = d
    # puts "test = #{test}, d = #{d}"
    break if test % d != 0
  end
  if divisor == 11 && test % divisor == 0
    puts "Answer = #{test}"
    exit
  end
  test += 20  # only need to check multiples of 20
end
```

Specifically, I'm not sure where in the code the numbers are multiplied, which yields 232,792,560.

Comment: I like @Brythan's answer [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67938/project-euler-5-lowest-multiple-of-1-through-20).

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896

Answer (score 1):

Don't know where you are stuck. This is a plain approach to calc lcm of 1-20, running very slow though.

This script has two loops, the outer one will plus test number by 20 each time. This is obvious, because the result must be a multiple of 20. Then we have `test += 20`.

For each test number, we need to divide it by every number from 20 to 11. (Actually only 19 to 11 needed.) No need to test 1 to 10. We have these factors included in 11-20. For example, if a num can be divided by 12, it is sure can be divided by 2 and 3.

After the inner loop is over or the `break` condition is true, we check if every factor is tested, to ensure the inner loop is not interrupted. If so, we find the answer then. The result is printed at this line: `puts "Answer = #{test}"`.